# EXCEL(VBA) How to pass an sql query value into a variable?

Tags: excel, mysql-5.1, vba

I'm using MySQL and EXCEL(VBA)
How can I  pass an sql query **value** into a variable?

I have a variable Dim-ed:

```
Dim sqlVar As Variant
```

It's variant because I'm not sure which type I should use.
I have set the sql query to the variable like this:

```
sqlVar = "SELECT datum FROM arfolyam ORDER BY datum ASC LIMIT 1 "
```

But like this, it stores the sql query, not the value of the query!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
Dim strSQL as String    
...
strSQL = "SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)   
variable1 = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

This way the sql query's value which is in this case is one cell, will be given to the variable1